# Numpy version and numba

Tags: python, numpy, version, numba

I am running some python (3.9.12) code and runs fine.
If I try to debug (with PyCharm) I get:
'AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes''

I googled it, and got the suggestion of upgrading my numpy, but then when I try to run it, comes up with this error:
importerror: numba needs numpy 1.21 or less.

Any other suggestions to get to be able to debug?

Comment: You need to update Numba so it use the last Numpy version. If you cannot use the last one, then you need to find the last compatible version. Such info should be available on pip website if not pip directly.

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround:

[image]

Changing this setting in PyCharm fixed it.